# OpenCV Manager - package was not found

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-emulator

I am a beginner to Android programming and my project involves using OpenCV... I was able to load the the sample examples onto my work space but when I run the example I encounter the following problem  opencv manager package was not found! try to install it?

I tried this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/android/service/doc/UseCases.html#how-to-select-the-proper-version-of-opencv-manager)

But could not understand how exactly to install it on Eclipse ...it'll be of great help if you can help me out....